# Google Closure Tools PriorityQueue wrong order

Tags: javascript, priority-queue, google-closure, google-closure-library

I've created a unique priority queue with an enqueue method like this:

```
huzz.ak.UniquePriorityQueue.prototype.enqueue =
    function(priority, value) {
  var node = {'valid': true, 'value': value, 'priority': priority};
  var key = value.key;
  if (this.pointers_[key] !== undefined) {
    this.pointers_[key].valid = false;
  }
  this.pointers_[key] = node;
  this.priorityQueue_.enqueue(priority, node);
};
```

When I output the values they come out in a random order:

```
while (true) {
  p = this.priorityQueue_.dequeue();
  this.logger_.log(p.priority + ' ' + p.value.toString() + ' ' + p.valid);
}

1265 ... true

1413 S..N. false

1265 ... false

92 S..N. true

1734 .........E false

59 ... false

75 ...B false

92 S..N. false
```

Why isn't the queue returning the values in the expected order (smallest to largest).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that in part of my code I was passing in a list instead of the length of the list and that screwed everything up. I fixed this error and the priority queue works as expected!